# Apply a fonction to multiple vectors stored in a numpy array without loops

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function taking two vectors with same size, making some calculations with them, and returning a third vector. Let's now consider that I have a multiple dimension array containing many vectors that I want to pass to my function as the first argument, and a fixed vector that I want to pass as the second argument. Below is an example. Is there a way to simplify the code by removing the loops?

```
def foo(x, y):
    result = np.zeros(x.shape)
    for i in range(y.size-1):
        result[i+1] = result[i] + (x[i+1] + x[i]) / (y[i+1] + y[i])
    return result

a = np.arange(2*3*4).reshape(2,3,4)
b = np.arange(4)*10
c = np.ones(a.shape)*-9999.
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    for j in range(a.shape[1]):
        c[i, j, :] = foo(a[i, j, :], b)
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: Below is the real function I'm trying to implement.

```
def press2alt(press, Tv):
    """
    Convert pressure level to altitude level with hydrostatic atmosphere calculation (hypsometric
    equation). The altitude reference (z = 0 km) is taken for the largest pressure level.
    :param press: pressure level profile [hPa]
    :param Tv: virtual temperature profile [K]
    :return: altitude level profile [km]
    """
    press_c = np.copy(press)
    if press[0] < press[1]:
        press_c = press_c[::-1] # high press first
        Tv = Tv[::-1]

    alt = np.zeros(press_c.size)
    for i in range(alt.size-1):
        alt[i+1] = alt[i] + DRY_AIR_GAS_CST/STD_GRAV_ACC*(Tv[i+1]-Tv[i])* \
                   (np.log(press_c[i])-np.log(press_c[i+1]))/(np.log(Tv[i+1])-np.log(Tv[i]))
    
    if press[0] < press[1]:
        alt = alt[::-1]
        
    return alt


# Get altitude at each pressure level
z = np.ones(tv.shape)*FILL_VALUE_FLOAT
    for i_month in range(tv.shape[0]):
        for i_lat in range(tv.shape[2]):
            for i_lon in range(tv.shape[3]):
                z[i_month, :, i_lat, i_lon] = \
                    press2alt(pressure_level, tv[i_month, :, i_lat, i_lon])
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be easy to do with a lambda?

Comment: I don't know. Could you provide an example please?

Comment: I'd recommend that you find some Python documentation about lambdas and do some research yourself.  That's a good hint.

Comment: Here, take a look at this: https://realpython.com/python-lambda/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, I still don't see why lambda would be useful to solve my problem...

Comment: Have you written any code?   You wanted no loops.

Comment: My first thought was to use numpy.tile to repeat the `b` vector in an array with same shape than the `a` array, so to directly use `c = foo(a, b)`. However, the function would then need to know which is the dimension on which to apply the `i` and `i+1` indexes. I understand lambda function can make anonymous functions but I don't see how this relate to my multidimensional array problem. Sorry, my knowledge in coding is quite poor...

Comment: `np.vectorize` can be used to remove loops. But do not expect a speed up since it use a (CPython) loop internally. Note that there is no way to automagically vectorize a CPython function without rewriting your code and actually remove the target function. There is sometime conflicts between performance and the design of a given software application. Anyway, neither the title nor the content talk about performance, so it should be fine, right?

Comment: Thank you! It starts looking to something that would do what I want. So far I don't worry about speed. I just want to make such kind of function the more generic possible. I mean that I want to simply do `c = foo(a, b)` with `a` array with any number of dimensions. For example with `a.shape: (12, 37, 90, 180)` and `b.size: 37`. Maybe I'll need to tell my function which axis of `a` is of same size than `b` with: `c = foo(a, b, axis=1)` in this example.

Comment: Try to write the function so it works with 2d (or higher) arrays from the start.  e.g. `result[...,i] + (x[...,i+1] + x[...,i]) / (y[...,i+1] + y[...,i])`  With the `i` and `i+1` it will be hard to eliminate the iteration on the last axis, but as far as I can tell, all the other dimensions are independent, so can be done all at once (i.e. true vectorization).

Comment: @duffymo, I don't see how `lambda` would help.  That's just another syntax for defining a function, which is what `def foo` is doing already.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, he wants to iterate on all but the last axis.  That can't be done in `vectorize` unless you use the `signature` parameter - which slows it down some more, and is harder to understand.

Comment: @hpaulj I agree, but if the OP really want to keep its function `foo` as it is, I see no other option. I think this is not a good idea though and the function should be adapted to be vectorized.

Answer (score 2):

The `c` from your sample (which you should have shown) is:

```
In [164]: c
Out[164]: 
array([[[0.        , 0.1       , 0.2       , 0.3       ],
        [0.        , 0.9       , 1.26666667, 1.52666667],
        [0.        , 1.7       , 2.33333333, 2.75333333]],

       [[0.        , 2.5       , 3.4       , 3.98      ],
        [0.        , 3.3       , 4.46666667, 5.20666667],
        [0.        , 4.1       , 5.53333333, 6.43333333]]])
```

`np.vectorize` with `signature` turns out to be easier to use than I first thought:

```
In [165]: f = np.vectorize(foo, signature="(n),(n)->(n)")
In [166]: f(a, b)
Out[166]: 
array([[[0.        , 0.1       , 0.2       , 0.3       ],
        [0.        , 0.9       , 1.26666667, 1.52666667],
        [0.        , 1.7       , 2.33333333, 2.75333333]],

       [[0.        , 2.5       , 3.4       , 3.98      ],
        [0.        , 3.3       , 4.46666667, 5.20666667],
        [0.        , 4.1       , 5.53333333, 6.43333333]]])
```

But `vectorize` does not improve speed:

```
In [167]: %%timeit
     ...: c = np.ones(a.shape)*-9999.
     ...: for i in range(a.shape[0]):
     ...:     for j in range(a.shape[1]):
     ...:         c[i, j, :] = foo(a[i, j, :], b)
     ...: 
57 µs ± 126 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
In [168]: timeit f(a, b)
206 µs ± 3.05 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

In other recent cases I've found that `vectorize` does improve in relative performance with larger arrays, but that wasn't with `signature`.

The function can be rewritten to accept arrays of any size, as long as the iteration on the last dimension is correct.  Basically I use `...` in the indexing:

```
def myfoo(a, b):
    result = np.zeros(a.shape)
    for i in range(a.shape[-1] - 1):
        result[..., i + 1] = result[..., i] + (a[..., i + 1] + 
             a[...,i]) / ( b[..., i + 1] + b[..., i])
    return result

In [182]: myfoo(a, b)
Out[182]: 
array([[[0.        , 0.1       , 0.2       , 0.3       ],
        [0.        , 0.9       , 1.26666667, 1.52666667],
        [0.        , 1.7       , 2.33333333, 2.75333333]],

       [[0.        , 2.5       , 3.4       , 3.98      ],
        [0.        , 3.3       , 4.46666667, 5.20666667],
        [0.        , 4.1       , 5.53333333, 6.43333333]]])
In [183]: timeit myfoo(a, b)
65.8 µs ± 483 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

This doesn't help with speed, possibly because the last axis, size 4, is comparable to the 2*3 iterations of the first.  I expect it will do better, relatively, if the initial dimensions get much larger.

We may be able to improve speed by replacing the `i` iteration on:

```
(a[..., i + 1] + a[...,i]) / ( b[..., i + 1] + b[..., i])
```

with

```
(a[...,1:]+a[...,:-1])/(b[...,1:]+b[...,:-1])
```

## edit

```
In [192]: ab = (a[..., 1:] + a[..., :-1]) / (b[..., 1:] + b[..., :-1])
In [193]: ab
Out[193]: 
array([[[0.1       , 0.1       , 0.1       ],
        [0.9       , 0.36666667, 0.26      ],
        [1.7       , 0.63333333, 0.42      ]],

       [[2.5       , 0.9       , 0.58      ],
        [3.3       , 1.16666667, 0.74      ],
        [4.1       , 1.43333333, 0.9       ]]])
In [194]: ab.cumsum(axis=2)
Out[194]: 
array([[[0.1       , 0.2       , 0.3       ],
        [0.9       , 1.26666667, 1.52666667],
        [1.7       , 2.33333333, 2.75333333]],

       [[2.5       , 3.4       , 3.98      ],
        [3.3       , 4.46666667, 5.20666667],
        [4.1       , 5.53333333, 6.43333333]]])
```

Those are the values - except for the leading 0's column.

```
In [195]: timeit((a[..., 1:] + a[..., :-1]) / (b[..., 1:] + b[..., :-1])).cumsum
     ...: (axis=2)
18.8 µs ± 36.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Comment: I guess the speed should be bounded by the allocation of the several temporary array, the overhead of Numpy operations on small array and possibly the fact that accesses are not contiguous (if so, a transposition may help a bit tough the Numpy transposition is not very efficient).

Comment: Thank you so much! What's the name of "..." syntax? I'd like to know more about it as it seems very useful. What if the iterations in the function is not on the last dimension? About the vectorize function, looks great too but I don't understand the syntax for signature ("(n),(n)->(n)").

Comment: It's the `ellipsis`.  It's recognized by the Python interpreter, but only `numpy` uses it.  It stands for "a variable number of slices, ':'`.  `x[...,3,:]` would apply 3 to the 2nd to the last dimension.  Here the `signature` just tells `vectorize` to pass matching 1d arrays (last dimension) to the function, and expect back the same.  I wouldn't put too much effort into understanding `np.vectorize`.

Comment: I've added my real function to my first post. The "iterable" dimension of the `tv` array is not the first neither the last dimension. Then I don't see how to use the ellipsis. Moreover, the "iterable" dimension would not necessary always be the same.